# Use data passed to a component in the componentdidmount method

Tags: reactjs

I have a component called PrivateDataSingle below. I am able to pass customer data to this component
from anywhere I am

```
    <PrivateDataSingle customer={this.state.customer}/> :
```

I want to use the customerId contained in my customer data in the method componentDidMount.
This will be used as part of an api to return data.

It seems as if my customer information does not exist in componentDidMount method. How can I make
this available ?

It exists in the other sections of the component though.

```
    class PrivateDataSingle extends PureComponent {
         state = {
           invoices:[]
         }

         componentDidMount() {
          const getCustomerId = customer.customerId; ??
          AXIOS_AUTHED.get(`${API}/customers/${getCustomerId}/invoices`)
            .then(res => {
              const invoices= res.data;
              this.setState({ invoices });
            })  
        }

      render() {
        return (
          <h2>Hello world</h2>
        );
      }
    }

    export default PrivateDataSingle;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you render your component this way:

```
<PrivateDataSingle customer={this.state.customer} />
```

You are passing `customer` as a prop.

In your `componentDidMount` you can retrieve it this way:

```
const getCustomerId = this.props.customer.customerId;
```